# Equivalency of two free body diagrams

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram

**Question-1**
Are the cases (i) and (ii) same in the following figure so that I can use any of of them to get similar results like force on $2\, \rm kg$ and $5\,\rm kg$?

[image: img]

Here , the acceleration is $a=5 ms^{-2}$

**Question-2**

Are the free body diagrams in the following pictures equivalent?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1: If all of the masses are connected then yes, both scenarios will result in the same overall movement. If they are not connected then in the second diagram the mass on the right will just move away and the other two will stay where they are.

2: You want your free body diagram to only involve forces acting on the body you are drawing your diagram for. So in your one labeled ii you technically don't want to have forces the 5kg mass exerts on the other blocks, even though you can say the magnitudes are equal to the forces in diagram i due to Newton's third law. The first diagram labeled i is correct.

Comment: Almost a great answer.  But I think that the two diagrams in $1$ describe two different physical situations, one pushing the other pulling, so they can't be said to be equivalent.  Upvote, nonetheless.

Comment: Yeah that's why I said they will result in the same motion if they are connected. I tend to not be as picky about where arrows are in a FBD unless torques are involved. But I agree with you, the downside to that is confusing pushing with pulling.

Comment: @AaronStevens...whether it is pulling or pushing , the mathematical results would be unaltered , right ?

Comment: Yes that's what I was trying to get at. The net forces and accelerations will be the same.